# Adding child element at Library Item

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, addchild

i have a problem on as3, i want to add textfield at movieclip,

you can see at the first image, it has one row as you see. But i need more than one row. I trying to develop a component. This will be get the date from xml file and listing these data(xml data).

when i add the one row its ok, but when i use loop (it is necessary for multiple rows) it isnt work, textfield is adding but background movieclip(it is located as a symbol at my library (WhiteLine)) is not!.

this code is works succesfully,

```
            var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();      
            myTextField.text = "some text here!";  
            myTextField.width = 250;  
            myTextField.x = 0;  
            myTextField.y = 0;
            myTextField.selectable = true;  
            myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;  
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
            myFormat.color = 0xAA0000;
            myFormat.size = 12; 
            myFormat.italic = true;
            myTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat);  
            item =  new WhiteLine;
            item.x = 1;
            item.y = (i*30)+1+3*i;
            item.addChild(myTextField);
            avatar.addChild(item);              
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, listItemOver);
```

here is screenshot of result,
[image: //resim]

but when i use the loop, i getting this result
[image: resim2]

and here is the code with loop

```
        for(var i:int=0;i<25;i++)
        {               
            var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();      
            myTextField.text = "some text here!";  
            myTextField.width = 250;  
            myTextField.x = 0;  
            myTextField.y = 0;
            myTextField.selectable = true;  
            myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;  
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
            myFormat.color = 0xAA0000;
            myFormat.size = 12; 
            myFormat.italic = true;
            myTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat);  
            item =  new WhiteLine;
            item.x = 1;
            item.y = (i*30)+1+3*i;
            item.addChild(myTextField);
            avatar.addChild(item);              
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, listItemOver);             
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the loop is for, or why you are adding it.

Comment: @Gus i added the screenshot, "item" is the the background of the first row and i want to do at all, also i want to add textfield all of these "items", i used for loop because i will get the data list from xml file (there there will be more than one row)

Comment: also who has done downvote thanks to him! my question is not bad for downvote!

Comment: Your question is of the form: A works but when I do B it doesn't work, what should I do?... The only answer that comes to mind is "don't do B". We cant read your mind. Edit your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve with the additional for loop and I'll remove my downvote. What would *success* look like? (draw or describe it)? If we know what you want, we might be able to help you achieve it.

Comment: isnt it clear ?. I will have to "B" because i need multiple rows. ok i expanding my question.

Comment: You're trying to accomplish something I was trying to do a couple of months ago. I won't bother linking you to the finished source because I think I might have "misplaced" it but this tutorial (http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-smooth-rolling-scroller-with-as3--active-4356?request_uri=%2Ftutorials%2Factionscript%2Fcreate-a-smooth-rolling-scroller-with-as3%2F) is exactly what you need - scrolling list with a loop for external xml file. If you look at steps 11 & 12, those are pretty much what you're doing right now.

Comment: @adaam my problem isnt scroling my problem is adding to content rows

Comment: (look at steps 11 and 12). You need a `dataLoad()` method to load the xml data and then a `dataLoaded()` method to consume that data and loop through it and place it into the textfield

Comment: @adaam no tried your example but same result :(

Comment: @EnginYıldırım Let me just mock something up for you..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your loop to consume data from an XML file you need to load the xml data from an external XML file like so (I've mocked this up very quickly - I've  created an example using a document class - if you are writing your actionscript in the Flash timeline, then you will need to modify this code)

```
package {
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.Font;

public var loader:URLLoader;
public var data:XML;
public var items:XMLList;

public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {
public function DocumentClass() {
            dataLoad();    
}
private function dataLoad():void {
    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded); 
    loader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml")); // change data.xml to your xml file's path
} // end of dataLoad()

private function dataLoaded(event:Event):void {
// this property holds the loaded xml data
    data = new XML(event.target.data); // event.target.data relates to the dataLoad() function that results in dataLoaded() being called  

    // the items property holds all the repeating item elements
    items = data.item;

    // beginning of loop - items.length is the number of items in the xml file
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();      
    addChild(myTextField);
    myTextField.text = items[i].toString();
    myTextField.width = 250;  
    myTextField.x = 0;  
    myTextField.y = 0;
    myTextField.selectable = true;  
    myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;  
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
    myFormat.color = 0xAA0000;
    myFormat.size = 12; 
    myFormat.italic = true;
    myTextField.setTextFormat(myFormat); 
    item =  new WhiteLine;
    item.x = 1;
    item.y = (i*30)+1+3*i;
    item.addChild(myTextField);
    avatar.addChild(item);
    } // end of loop
    } // end of dataLoaded()
  } // end of class  
} // end of package
```